# How to input a different value in each space on a grid

Tags: java

Hey im new to java in grade 10 and I came through a small problem. I'm creating the game 4 pics on word and I can't seem to put a different image in each square of my grid.

Here is the grid

The decleration:

```
int row = 4;
int col = 4;
JButton a[] = new JButton [row * col];
```

And here's the array:

```
card4 = new Panel ();
Panel g = new Panel (new GridLayout (row, col));
for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
{
   a[i] = new JButton ("Hi");
   a[i].setPreferredSize (new Dimension (50,50));
   g.add (a[i]);
}
```

How would I call out each individual button on the grid and assign a different image to it?

Comment: Use constructor that takes an Icon, e.g. `new JButton(String, Icon)`

Comment: im slightly confused can you please just elaborate a little bit, like a slightly extended example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you run `new JButton("Hi")`, you are invoking (one of) the constructor(s) for the class.  JButton has several different constructors taking different parameters.  One of those constructors is `JButton(String text, Icon icon)`, that allows specifying an Icon to draw in the button.  So, first you would have to create an Icon and then create the button using it, like:

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon("name/of/file/containing/icon/image");
a[i] = new JButton("Button Text", icon);
```

If you only want an icon and no text, then just use:

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon("name/of/file/containing/icon/image");
a[i] = new JButton(icon);
```

The file containing the image can be a jpg, png, gif.  Look in Java Tutorial on now to use images and controls.